# Problem with file ".ssh/rc" and option "ForceCommand". Script python loop infinite!

Tags: linux, ssh, scripting, python

As the title suggests, I have a python script to run when logging in with ssh.  The problem is that in the script there is a "while" loop with "raw_input" inside which must read a keyboard value.  If I run the script normally everything works ... if instead I run it ssh after logging in, it enters an infinite loop ... how is it possible !?

```
while True:
      try:
             value=raw_input('insert number: ")
             .....
       except:
             ......
```

This is part of my code....only on ssh not work. If launched normally, everything works properly

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this script or at least the relevant parts of it. And show how you're running ssh when this script is invoked.

Comment: What you show in your question is an infinite loop that will never exit. Maybe add some code to show your exit condition?

Comment: this is just a "sketch".  The complete code also contains "exits" ... but this is not the point since the script normally WORKS ... only via ssh no ...